# How to Get returned value from php in PHP

Tags: php

I am using two files in php. one for calling the function. and another one is do process and return json object.

My question is,

How to get returned value from php.

File1 calling function--

```
$realtimestatsObj = new realtimestats();
$realtimestatsObj -> getDetails($imei, $con);
echo $realtimestatsObj;
```

File2 Return value--

```
$response = json_encode($realtimestats);
return $response;
```

Here file 2 return some value.. How to  get return value and use that value in File1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the result in a variable and echo:

```
$result = $realtimestatsObj->getDetails($imei, $con);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: One more thing, I have return value like this..  {"imei":"imei1","details":[{"deviceId":"7")]}.. Here how to get imei value and deviveId value

Comment: How to show imei value..  $final_result.imei. is corret?

Comment: For imei  $final->imei,, but for deviceId?

Comment: Try $final_result->details->deviceId or $final_result->details['deviceId']

Comment: It gives undefined index

Comment: $final_result->details[0]->deviceId;